# Midori Browser as alternative for Safari testing

Tags: 20.04, browser, webkit, midori

A webpage that I am developing currently has been reported to not display correctly in safari by some users. Unfortunately, I only have Windows 10 and Fedora 20 on my laptop. I saw on internet that Safari browsers are built on top of Webkit engine which is also the engine being used by Midori browser.
So can I use Midori for conducting my tests are could you suggest me some other alternative.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  (The only OSes you mention are off-topic here)